# Using same data set for two worksheets

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
ID      RL      Category    

12345   High    MSB  
12345   High    NRA  
24680   Low     MSB  
12121   High    NNN
```

I would like to make a pie chart whose slices are the RL column, but I don't want to double count the rows that are identical except for the Category column.  For example, the High slice should = 2, not 3.

Thought I'd get it by using COUNTD() somehow but pretty much stuck.

Altering the data source or creating a new one isn't an option because I am using it in another worksheet and don't want to give up the functionality of the global filter that's available if your sheets share a source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a Calc field that is countd (ID) and then put the RL field on the detail button and then that countd on the angle button it should work.

Comment: don't really even need to make a calc field, just put ID on the angle shelf and select the COUNTD() aggregation for it. You'll have to treat ID as a measure for that to work. The easiest way is to hold down the right mouse button on windows when you drag ID to the shelf, and then select COUNTD().